# Is Viro -React app be independent appication?

Tags: react-native, viro-react

I have a question: I'm going to develop an AR app with [viro for react native](https://viromedia.com/viroreact/).

Will I be able to publish the project without the [Viro Media](https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/quick-start) app that they're suggesting for development?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can create an independent Viro app and build it either from Android Studio or by exploiting the React Native CLI, [as it is described here.](https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/installing-viro-android)
Remember to use an ARCore supported device to access native modules and the AR functionalities.